# Select dynamic dropbox

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am at the website: https://www.mister-auto.com/
In the section "En sélectionnant mon véhicule", I want to select a brand 'Peugeot', model '107 [06/2005' and a motor of the car '1.0 (68Cv), I tried this for the brand but doesn' t work:

```
Select option = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("/div[@class='dropdown'][1]/select[@class='form-control col-xs-12 ng-pristine ng-valid ng-not-empty ng-touched']")));
option.selectByVisibleText("Peugeot");
```

Any idea why?

Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@ng-model='brand_id']"));
Select option=new Select(element);
option.selectByValue("88");
```

Now if you have to click on model 1007 in the subsequent dropdown for Peugeout you need to use JavascriptExecutor like below. This is because its an optgroup element and there is nothing in Select class for optgroup yet.

```
WebElement element2=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@ng-model='model_id']"));
element2.click();
WebElement element1=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@ng-model='model_id']/optgroup[contains(@label,'1007')]"));
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element1);
```

Comment: for the motor, i typed:         WebElement element2=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@ng-model='model_id']"));
        Select option2=new Select(element2);
        option2.selectByValue("/peugeot-1007-km-1-4-75ch_v18431.html"); but doesn' t seems ok, i chose Peugeot > 1007 > then the motor

Comment: ng-model should be 'vehicle_uri' for third dropdown. Please try : WebElement element2=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@ng-model='vehicle_uri']")); Select option2=new Select(element2); option2.selectByValue("/peugeot-1007-km-1-4-75ch_v18431.html")

Comment: @dtjmsy you need to first click on the element2. Then use JavascriptExecutor to click on the xpath for the 1007 model. Please take a look at my updated answer.